# Parsing json data in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Hi I have a json file from where I am retrieving data I have different keys in different json array
I wanna show the key along side data inside that

Main to focus is appDetails Like in first json array It has 3 keys systemOverview benefits and mainFeatures.

But in next array it doesn't have system overview have other keys.

**What I wanna do is show both key and data correspondance to that**

```json
{
  "name": "Parts",
  "category": "Production",
  "subcategory": "Productivity",
  "imageUrl": "PI-Banner.jpg",
  "logo": "PI.png",
  "description": "(PI) is an application for easy & effective Quality.The application is supported on Android tablet devices and iPads.",
  "appDetails": [
    {
      "systemOverview": "pi_overview.jpg",
      "Benefits": [
        {
          "label": "Multi-lingual support"
        },
        {
          "label": "Support for different screen sizes"
        }
      ],
      "mainFeatures": [
        
        {
          "label": "Import details"
        }
       
      ]
    }

  ]
},
{
  "name": "Feedback System",
  "category": "Production",
  "subcategory": "Productivity",
  "imageUrl": "ADFbanner.jpg",
  "description": "A smartphone and tablet-based solution to register",
  "appDetails": [
    {

      "testing": [
        {
          "label": "Multi-Device"
        },
        {
          "label": "Multi-Lingual"
        },
        {
          "label": "Multi-Database"
        }
      ],
      "mainScreen": [
      
        {
          "label": "Select failure codes"
        },
        {
          "label": "Add comments & take evidence Pictures"
        },
       
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

**ProductModel** is the Model class generated by

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../models/models.dart';
class TestingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final ProductModel item;
  const TestingScreen({Key? key, required this.item}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestingScreen> createState() => _TestingScreenState();
}

class _TestingScreenState extends State<TestingScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:  Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
                left: BorderSide(
                    width: 5,
                    color: Color(0xffD9D9D9)))),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 10.0),
          child: Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 240,
              height: 130,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount:
                widget.item.appDetails?.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final detail =
                  widget.item.appDetails?[index];
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment:
                      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children:
                      (detail?.mainFeatures ?? [])
                          .map((e) {
                        // final index = (details?.multiDeviceSupport ?? []).indexOf(e);
                        return Row(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                                width: 20,
                                child: Text(
                                    '${index + 1}.',
                                    style: Theme.of(
                                        context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .bodyText1!
                                        .copyWith(
                                        fontWeight:
                                        FontWeight
                                            .w300))),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 2,
                              child: Text('${e.label}',
                                  style: Theme.of(
                                      context)
                                      .textTheme
                                      .bodyText1!
                                      .copyWith(
                                      fontWeight:
                                      FontWeight
                                          .w300,
                                      overflow:
                                      TextOverflow
                                          .clip)),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  );
                  // BuildProduct(: detail);
                  //buildProduct(detail);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
       
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Currently this is what I have done so far i.e. **using map Check listview**

```
class ProductModel {
  ProductModel({
    String? name,
    String? category,
    String? subcategory,
    String? imageUrl,
    String? logo,
    String? description,
    List<AppDetails>? appDetails,
    List<Region>? region,
  }) {
    _name = name;
    _category = category;
    _subcategory = subcategory;
    _imageUrl = imageUrl;
    _logo = logo;
    _description = description;
    _appDetails = appDetails;
    _region = region;
  }

  ProductModel.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _name = json['name'];
    _category = json['category'];
    _subcategory = json['subcategory'];
    _imageUrl = json['imageUrl'];
    _logo = json['logo'];
    _description = json['description'];
    if (json['appDetails'] != null) {
      _appDetails = [];
      json['appDetails'].forEach((v) {
        _appDetails?.add(AppDetails.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['region'] != null) {
      _region = [];
      json['region'].forEach((v) {
        _region?.add(Region.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
  String? _name;
  String? _category;
  String? _subcategory;
  String? _imageUrl;
  String? _logo;
  String? _description;
  List<AppDetails>? _appDetails;
  List<Region>? _region;
  ProductModel copyWith({
    String? name,
    String? category,
    String? subcategory,
    String? imageUrl,
    String? logo,
    String? description,
    List<AppDetails>? appDetails,
    List<Region>? region,
  }) =>
      ProductModel(
        name: name ?? _name,
        category: category ?? _category,
        subcategory: subcategory ?? _subcategory,
        imageUrl: imageUrl ?? _imageUrl,
        logo: logo ?? _logo,
        description: description ?? _description,
        appDetails: appDetails ?? _appDetails,
        region: region ?? _region,
      );
  String? get name => _name;
  String? get category => _category;
  String? get subcategory => _subcategory;
  String? get imageUrl => _imageUrl;
  String? get logo => _logo;
  String? get description => _description;
  List<AppDetails>? get appDetails => _appDetails;
  List<Region>? get region => _region;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['name'] = _name;
    map['category'] = _category;
    map['subcategory'] = _subcategory;
    map['imageUrl'] = _imageUrl;
    map['logo'] = _logo;
    map['description'] = _description;
    if (_appDetails != null) {
      map['appDetails'] = _appDetails?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (_region != null) {
      map['region'] = _region?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return map;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you include dataset where all appDetails info is available. This will help out in coming up with an algorithm to extract the data for null cases or empty cases.

Comment: Updated checkout